Is using Literal type hints violating DRY? Best practice ways to implement?
I am passing a data_type parameter to many python functions/methods/classes. It can take one of a small number of string values.
I could type hint it using Literal
from typing import Literal

data_type: Literal["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"]

But then if I add a new data type, I need to update this Literal type hint everywhere.
Does this violate the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle? What are some best practice ways to get around this?

How about type MyTypes = Literal["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"] and data_type: MyTypes? Then you can import MyTypes any where you need
